# Zener diode in series with load

Tags: diodes, zener

This may sound like a silly question, but what happens if we place a Zener diode in the reverse direction "in series" at the positive wire of the load without impedances other than the load itself?

Comment: The voltage across the load will be Vcc-Vzen and the load current (Vcc-Vzen) / Rload. Another words the load voltage will be decreased by zener voltage.

Answer (score 3):

If the input voltage source (Vin) is higher than the breakdown voltage of the zener, the zener will break down, dropping Vz (zener voltage) volts, and the load would receive Vin-Vz volts.  The zener would dissipate Vz*Iload watts, where Iload is the current drawn by the load.

If Vin is lower than the breakdown of the zener, then only a leakage current will flow and the load will presumably not work.

If there's sufficient voltage left across the load and it's within the specs for the load, then the load will work fine.

If there's insufficient voltage left across the load based on the load's requirements then the load may not work as desired.

If the power dissipated in the zener is too high the zener may fail.

Comment: Great. This is an absolute answer. Thx for info.
Is there any difference in this statement if the zener diode was on the negative wire (in reverse direction of the current of course)?

Comment: @IslamGhunym No difference, series is series.  There could be a difference if the load wants to connect to other things that are grounded, for example if the load is a microcontroller and you want to connect to some peripheral that's grounded.  The load wouldn't be sharing the common ground anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly your statement “Zener diode in the reverse direction”, you mean using the zener diode in reverse of its normal usage (anode and cathode in reverse). In this case, it will work like any normal diode in a forward voltage configuration, respecting the current and voltage limits mentioned by @JohnD.

You can use a zener diode in series in a circuit to reduce the power supply voltage. For instance, I have used a 10 volts zener diode to reduce a 12.6 volts battery power supply to 2.6 volts and use it to measure the battery state of charge with a set of opamp lighting up a series of leds.

Comment: I wondered about that too, it's kind of ambiguous.  I assumed the OP meant that the zener would be in reverse in the sense of opposite to where the junction is forward biased, i.e. the more common way to use a zener, but if not your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

the zenner diode fixes the load voltage only when they are  parallele.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?